# Appending various values to corresponding id's

Tags: jquery

I've created a small app that helps with creating long, repetitive product descriptions. There are several categories, under each there are many pre-made paragraphs; clicking on a paragraph will automatically add it to the full description that's being created (That's how it looks and works: https://gfycat.com/AnguishedBestChinesecrocodilelizard).

Each category has it's own variables. That's how the HTML looks like:

```
<!-- Setting variables -->
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <label for="resolution">Resolution:</label> <input type="text" id="resolution" placeholder="1234 x 4321">
  <input type="button" id="setresolution" value="SET"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <label for="quality">Quality:</label> <input type="text" id="quality" placeholder="ie. FullHD, HD, 4K, UHD">
  <input type="button" id="setquality" value="SET"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <label for="screensize">Screen size:</label> <input type="text" id="screensize" placeholder='w/ unit, ie. 4 inches or 4"'>
  <input type="button" id="setscreensize" value="SET"></div>
  (...)
  <!-- paragraphs with placeholders that will be replaced by values set above -->
<div class="box">&lt;div class=&quot;kol_<span class="kolx">100</span>&quot; style=&quot;text-align: center; &quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;<b>See more</b>&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;span&gt;<b> A big, <span class="inchx">[5,5"]</span> screen? Sure, why not. But only if it's <span class="qualityx">[QUALITY]</span> screen – just like here! An amazing <span class="qualityx">[QUALITY]</span> screen allows you to fully enjoy all those beautiful photos.</b>&lt;/span&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</div>
<div class="box">&lt;div class=&quot;kol_<span class="kolx">100</span>&quot; style=&quot;text-align: center; &quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;<b>Crystal clear</b>&lt;/h3&gt; &lt;span&gt;<b>This device has an amazing <span class="resolutionx">[RES]</span> screen, so you can see everything perfectly.</b>&lt;/span&gt; &lt;/div&gt;</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#setresolution").click(function() {
      $(".resolutionx").empty();
      $(".resolutionx").append($('#resolution').val());
      toastr.success('Done');
    });
  });
$(function() {
  $("#setquality").click(function() {
    $(".qualityx").empty();
    $(".qualityx").append($('#quality').val());
    toastr.success('Done');
    });
  });
$(function() {
    $("#setscreensize").click(function() {
      $(".inchx").empty();
      $(".inchx").append($('#screensize').val());
      toastr.success('Done');
    });
  });
```

It works, but it's very inelegant, as the JS piece is basically repeated over and over again with only targets changing. I was trying to create one bigger universal function to handle all cases, but I'm not sure how, as all my attempts so far failed.

Could anybody lend a hand? :)

Comment: Need to see more samples of what gets repeated as in a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl I added some more code, hopefully my intent (and problem) is now clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple application of *refactoring*.

You only appear to have three things that vary in each block:

- the selector for the button
- the selector for the field to contain the output
- the selector of the field containing the value

so those can be parameters to a function:

```
function registerField(button, clazz, field) {
    $(button).on('click', function() {
         $(clazz).empty().append($(field).val());
         toastr.success('Done');
    });
}
```

with sample usage:

```
$(function() {
    registerField('#setquality', '.qualityx', '#quality');
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I've tried it like this, but for some reason it didn't work – perhaps some typo, will try again.